# Pytest does not pick up test methods inside a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

Always worked with python `unittest2`, and just started migrating to `pytest`. Naturally I am trying to draw parallels and one thing I am just not able to figure out is:

**Question** Why does Pytest not pick up my test methods defined inside a "test" class.

**What works for me**

```
# login_test.py
import pytest
from frontend.app.login.login import LoginPage

@pytest.fixture
def setup():
    login = LoginPage()
    return login

def test_successful_login(setup):
    login = setup
    login.login("incorrect username","incorrect password")
    assert login.error_msg_label().text == 'Invalid Credentials'
```

**What does not work for me (Does not work = Test methods do not get discovered)**

```
# login_test.py 
import pytest
from frontend.app.login.login import LoginPage


class LoginTestSuite(object):

    @pytest.fixture
    def setup():
        login = LoginPage()
        return login

    def test_invalid_login(self, setup):
        login = setup
        login.login("incorrect username","incorrect password")
        assert login.error_msg_label().text == 'Invalid Credentials'
```

In `pytest.ini` I have

```
# pytest.ini
[pytest]
python_files = *_test.py
python_classes = *TestSuite
# Also tried
# python_classes = *
# That does not work either
```

Not sure what other information is necessary to debug this?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you use the default naming convention, i.e. `TestSuiteLogin`? Are you sure the `.ini` is being used?

Comment: Does not work with `TestSuiteLogin` as well. I am almost certain `pytest.ini` it is being picked up, as when I change the `python_files` value to say `*_xyz`, it does not discover the tests.

Comment: Well that does seem odd. It won't find old-style classes, but if you're using 3.x that's not a problem. Does it find it if you subclass `unittest.TestCase`?

Comment: I edited my question to make it a new style class. Also it does discover the test if i subclass `unittest.TestCase` (the execution fails, but it discovers). However I intend to get `unittest` out of the equation.

Comment: In 3.x you don't need to explicitly subclass `object` to get a new-style class, which is why I said it isn't a problem. This seems very odd!

Comment: Dint know @3.x not needing an explicit subclass to get a new-style. Yes it is very odd. As I see plenty of examples on py.test's docs where they use classes. Also, there is no way I can debug, by switching some `veryverbose` option either. :/

Comment: @jonrsharpe, okay some progress, when i run `py.test` from a folder higher then it picks it up. Does this data point help ?

Comment: I tried your example and it works for me (well, except that it complains about `setup()` missing `self`, but the test is picked up). From which directory are you running py.test? Could you please add the output you are getting?

Comment: Okay figured the reason, or so I think. If I have any thing about  `python_classes=` inside pytest.ini it does not work. Which even means an all match  `python_classes=*`. Once I remove/comment that line it works.

Answer (score 12):

I was just running into a similar problem. I found that if you name your classes starting with "Test" then pytest will pick them up, otherwise your test class will not get discovered.

This works:

```
class TestClass:
    def test_one(self):
        assert 0
```

This does not:

```
class ClassTest:
    def test_one(self):
        assert 0
```

Comment: I just change testClass to **T**estClass and it works

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't the class have to subclass unittest.TestCase?

And using py.test, why would you want to re-introduce the class boilerplate?  One of the principles of py.test is to minimize boilerplate!

Here are the default conventions in the docs:

http://pytest.org/latest/goodpractises.html#python-test-discovery

Comment: Pytest does not require to subclass from unittest to use a Test Class. Also using test classes have it's own advantages. One example a single command marking for a bunch of tests- http://pytest.org/latest/example/markers.html#marking-whole-classes-or-modules