# How to execute test from inside a class in pytest?

Tags: python, pytest

I am trying to run a test method which is inside a class in Python using pytest framework.

Not sure what is going wrong, but the test is not getting picked. I made sure the package name, module name, class name and function name starts with "test".

There is no content inside **init**.py, I am not sure if I need to include anything inside this file to make sure the test(s) are picked which are under the class.

The interpreter I am using is shown in the screenshot. Also, I have added a screenshot showing the code so it becomes easier to understand the directory structure.

I visited several blogs and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31971415/pytest-does-not-pick-up-test-methods-inside-a-class), but none of them helped me resolve this.

Could you please help?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, pytest expects test classes to be named in `CamelCase`: `TestDemo`, not `test_demo`. The rest of your names follow the correct schema for the defaults, so if you change the class name to `TestDemo`, pytest should be able to find it.

pytest docs on test discovery: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/example/pythoncollection.html

Comment: @Prabodh: `CamelCase` class names also happens to be the naming convention recommended in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) — so you should be doing things that way, regardless.

Answer (score 6):

To test a function in a class with pytest, we can use this command:

```bash
$ pytest -v /path/to/test_file.py::ClassName::test_function_name
```

remember use "**::**"

Comment: this is what i needed. go get some more reputation